# Create 2D array from file for HMM package R

Tags: r, vector, hidden-markov-models

I am working with R [HMM package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/HMM/index.html). I have a file with symbols on each line. I need to create 2D vector from this file, where i-th vector contains symbols from i-th line

I wrote code likes:

```
q4 = readLines("someFile")
c1 <- strsplit(q4[1],"")[[1]]
c2 <- strsplit(q4[2],"")[[1]]
c3 <- strsplit(q4[3],"")[[1]]
baumWelch(hmm, c(c1,c2,c3), 10)
```

and it works. But I have 50000 lines, so I need to do it in loop. So I wrote this one:

```
q4 = readLines("someFile")
results <- vector(length=length(q4))
for (i in 1:length(q4)) {
   results[i] <- strsplit(q4[i],"")[[1]]
}
baumWelch(hmm, results, 10)
```

But each vectors contained only first symbol from the line. So I removed

```
[[1]]
```

from code, but type of results was list and not vector so I can not use it. How can I do it correctly?

Comment: Why you evaluate `results` while you are using `c(c1,c2,c3)` in the call of `baumWelch`? Also, `strsplit` is vectorized, so no need of a loop. Don't know the package, but I guess that you are looking for `baumWelch(hmm, do.call(rbind,strsplit(q4,"")),10)`.

Comment: I copied and pasted this line and forgot to change it. Now it is fixed. Your code has a problem with: number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)

Comment: Does every line have the same number of elements? Are you sure you want to pass a `matrix` object (which is a 2D array in R) or you need a `list`? Do you know the difference?